# Changing prefix in ConsoleTraceListener

Tags: c#, .net

At least by default, `ConsoleTraceListener` starts its trace messages with the name of the executable and the mode. E.g.:

```
myExecutable.exe Information: 0 : Saving 3602 row(s)...
```

It's a bit of an eyesore. Is there a way to get rid of the prefix and only output the message itself except inheriting and overriding the class?

Sorry of it's too much of a first world problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can customize the format of the trace messages that are output by the **ConsoleTraceListener** but you'll have to override it as far as I know.

To do this, you need to create a new class that derives from **ConsoleTraceListener** and override the **TraceEvent** method.

In the overridden method, you can use the base implementation of the method to get the default formatting for the trace message, and then modify it to remove the prefix.

Here is an example of how to create a custom **ConsoleTraceListener** that removes the prefix from trace messages:

```cs
    public class CustomConsoleTraceListener : ConsoleTraceListener
    {
        public CustomConsoleTraceListener()
        {
        }
    
        public override void TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string message)
        {
            // Call the base implementation to get the default formatting for the trace message
            string formattedMessage = base.FormatMessage(eventCache, source, eventType, id, message);
    
            // Remove the prefix from the formatted message
            int index = formattedMessage.IndexOf(" : ");
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                formattedMessage = formattedMessage.Substring(index + 3);
            }
    
            // Output the formatted message to the console
            Console.WriteLine(formattedMessage);
        }
    }
```

To use the custom **ConsoleTraceListener**, you simply create an instance of the **CustomConsoleTraceListener** class and add it to the **Trace.Listeners** collection:

```cs
CustomConsoleTraceListener listener = new CustomConsoleTraceListener();
Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);
```

It's a bit of a pain in the code but hope this helps!

I'll try achieving this without overriding the method, I'll edit my answer if I manage to do it properly.

Comment: The default format string for ConsoleTraceListener is "{0}: {1} : {2}", where {0} is the name of the application, {1} is the severity level, and {2} is the message text.


ConsoleTraceListener listener = new ConsoleTraceListener();

listener.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.DateTime | TraceOptions.ProcessId;

Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);